# Github and assembla: link issue and tickets

Tags: github, assembla

We manage tickets through assembla and source-code through github.com

I do not want to close tickets automatically when I mention in a ticket number in a commit message. But what I want to be able to do is that when I click on a ticket number in assembla  in github I want to be taken to corresponding ticket on assembla website.

Larger question is can I have URL's in git commit messages. We do not mind having to copy them  manually. But on github commit list we want to be able to see which ticket on assembla was referred to in that commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use correct tools by correct way. Select ["Ticket and Collaboration Tools for Github Repositories"](https://www.assembla.com/catalog/13-ticket-and-collaboration-tools-for-github-repositories-package) on Assembla side as preconfigured space type instead of unrelated repo on Github and space with tickets on Assembla

Answer (score 3):

The type of integration you want is available at Assembla with a lot less trouble.  It also includes a tight integration with your tickets and merge requests.  Giving you a place to follow the entire conversation of the ticket discussion and the code history.

However, that is not your question.  The answer is yes, you can have links in your github commit messages.  So just put them in and they will render fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your commit message just add

```
Ticket #<number>.
```

For example:

```
Ticket #123
```

Note that the Capital T is mandatory.
Then, when you view your commits, you will see it like that:
[image]